# error :Operand type clash: image is incompatible with ntext

Tags: sql, database

error :Operand type clash: image is incompatible with ntext

```
SELECT (case when COL_NAME='photocontent' 
             then NEW_VALUE_LONG
             else NEW_VALUE_BLOB
        end)  AS VAL
FROM VUTBL;
```

Comment: Okay.  Don't try to put both into the same column.  What is your issue?

Comment: I have to be both in a column @GordonLinoff

Comment: All return types for a case expression must be compatible. Seems like "image is incompatible with ntext"...